# Windows computers getting slower over time

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance

I have a small business that basically fixes computer problems (any kind). I'm on business since 24 years now, so I've seen hundreds of computers with very different hardware/software/problems in my life. I currently have hundreds of clients, so I know what I'm doing.

Lately (2 years or so) many clients are asking me to fix computers that are getting VERY slow. Computers that were performing "fine", now can't boot without a 10' delay. And every program you start takes ages.

I tend to do always the same solution: do a Windows Update via Windows Update Assistant (not Windows Update), clean up files/programs/malware, and HDD defrag. That was a good solution... until a couple of months ago. Now, sometimes even this won't cure the problem.

Most of the time, the culprit is the HDD. In task manager, I can see 100% of HDD usage (mostly on System). Changing HDD to SSD fixes the problem, but I wonder, and this is the question:

WHY some Windows computers with HDD drives start with this problem? Even a Windows restore won't fix the problem, so it's not a "programs/malware" problem, but seems to be a WINDOWS problem, or an HDD problem losing performance.

Any clue?

Comment: Have you tried checking the problem HDDs for SMART errors?

Comment: I tend to do always the same solution: do a Windows Update via Windows Update Assistant (not Windows Update), clean up files/programs/malware, and HDD defrag.      .......   Make sure Disk Cleanup is set to (a) cleanup System Files and (b) that all categories have been selected for cleanup.

Comment: My first question is WHAT exactly is pegging out the HDD?  It's not like the drive taxes itself.  I would use the system internals process monitor to figure out where the load is coming from.  Moving from HDD to SSD is great but it is nothing but a band-aid on the problem.  Your I/O is STILL getting taxed but the SSD makes it way less noticeable.

Comment: #DavidPostill
Yes. In some cases I've seen HDDs with bad sectors. Sometimes only with "Uncorrectaable errors", and sometimes the HDD is 100% OK.
#John
I always do that with the system files, and also use Glary Utilities

Comment: #Señor CMasMas
That's a good question. Task manager only shows "System", and on the details there's the Kernel only. Next time I'll check with ProcMon. I've tried with ProcExp to no avail.

Comment: Windows accumulates rollback data after each update. WinSxS gets larger, and when booting, it takes longer each time for the OS to search for new updates. One way around that is to clean up old update information with *DISM /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase* This **precludes rolling back to old versions,** though. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11

Comment: #DrMoishe Pippik:
I've noticed that a Windows Update to a newer version (a feature update version) is NOT the same as doing the same update via Windows Update Assistant. WU way is faster, but WUA way tends to leave your OS in a better shape (usually faster). Did you measure the impact of doing the WinSxS cleanup you mentioned?
I sometimes use PatchCleaner to clean some of the garbage that Windows accumulates over time (I remember that a Windows 8.1 once had more than 40GB of cleanable patches!)

Comment: > "Even a Windows restore won't fix the problem, so it's not a "programs/malware" problem, but seems to be a WINDOWS problem, or an HDD problem losing performance." So are you saying that even when you re-install Windows the problem remains? Or only when restoring to an earlier system restore point?

Comment: "Or only when restoring to an earlier system restore point?" yes, that's the case. If you do a clean installation, everything works OK